# Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0 when passing array from php to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to send array from php to ajax in json file but when i alert res var for testing it i see this error message :

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0

My array is this :

```
["C", "Dbm", "Bb", "Bb", "F", "Cm", "Eb", "Dbm", "Bb", "Bb", "F", "Cm", "F", "Bb", "Eb", "Bb", "F",…]
```

My array created by php function and array item's will different when user clicking on a button in view .

Java Script :

```
$(".T-chords").on('click',function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    var This = $(this);
    $.ajax({

        url : data.ajax_url,
        type : 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data : {

            action : 'transpose_callback',
            content : data.content,
            target_scale : This.text(),
            base_scale : data.base_scale,
        },

        success:function(response){

            var res = JSON.parse(response);
            alert(res[1]);

        },

        error: function(){

            alert("err");

        }


    })

})
```

php code :

```
function Ajax_transpose_callback(){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $Target_Scale = $_POST['target_scale'];
    $Base_Scale = $_POST['base_scale'];
    $Flag_db = "";
    $transposed_chord = "";
    $transposed_arr = array();

    if(preg_grep('/#/', $content)){
        $Flag_db = "0";
    }
    elseif (preg_grep('/b/', $content)){
        $Flag_db = "1";
    }
    else{
        $Flag_db = "0";
    }

    foreach ($content as $item) {

        $final_item = substr( $item, 1, - 1 );
        $transposed_arr[] = Transpose( $Flag_db, $Base_Scale, $Target_Scale, $final_item );

    }
    wp_die(json_encode($transposed_arr));
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what really is received in `success` function?

Comment: Can you show us what's in the res variable?

Comment: @O.S.Kaya They can't, because the error breaks the code before reading `res`.

Comment: @Teemu I copied this from inspect element > network > response     ["Eb","Dbm","Bb","Bb","F","Cm","Eb","Dbm","Bb","Bb","F","Cm","F","Bb","Eb","Bb","F","Bb","F","Eb","Bb","F","Cm","Bb","Cm","F","Bb","Bb","F","Cm","Bb","Bb","F","Cm"]

Comment: That has to be some other response, since the error message says the first character being `C` ..? Log the response to the console before trying to parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is either because you are parsing a already parsed object. Try to remove `var res = JSON.parse(response);` and change it to `var res = response;`

Comment: @SajjaDEbrahimiRaaD You're explicitly setting `dataType: 'json'`, jQuery parses the response for you before running the success function.

Answer (score 3):

You could fixed it either in 2 way, 
1)   Replace 
         var res = JSON.parse(response);
         alert(res[1]);
        With
          var res = response;
         alert(res[1]);

because here you will get an array, instead of an JSON Object.
2) Or you could pass an associative array here

```
$transposed_arr = array("c"=>"C", "Dbm"=>"Dbm","Bb" =>"Bb");
     json_encode($transposed_arr)
```

An associative array will product a JSON object, on which you could apply

```
 var res = JSON.parse(response);
```